# Is it good practice to pass open recordset to functions and procedures?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently structuring my project in Access 2010. I will have a main Form where the data is shown and various buttons to do calculations via VBA. To save time and complexity I am thinking of leaving out the whole:

```
dim db as database
dim rs as recordset
set db = current.db
set rs = db.(somerecord)
somestuff
rs.close
set rs = nothing
db.close
```

for each function and subprocedure. Instead open the respective recordset in the main procedure and pass the open recordset. What could go wrong?